# Data flow of subscription in multitenant microservice architechture

Tags: sass, microservices, multi-tenant, subscription

I am new to microservices , and currently designing a SASS based multi tenant application . now i have 4 services , one for auth related activities , one for user ,roles and rbac, one for tenant and one for subscription related activities  all the services have their own respective DB's. now since its a multi tenant application. I am not able to decide the data flow for subscriptions ,shoudl the subscription attribute of the current subscribe plan be stored on the login on frntend side or should i query the subscription service each time an activity happens to validated if that activity is permitted in subscription ?
if possible can you please show the data flow for subscription data for a sass based multi tenant system ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have already logged in the customer, now you want to check on the actions if the user is already subscribed or not.
As a basic approach, you could hit the subscription service every time.
To reduce the number of calls you can cache this value at the front-end in local-storage or session-storage depending upon your needs. Though, this data can be altered by someone who knows how to work around these storages. Hence any action that is critical e.g. downloading some document, you'll need to validate it again on the server side.

Regarding your 2nd part of the question, it seems like a different question or it needs more elaboration.

PS: Multi-tenancy should not have any impact on this flow, in any given request, you would be accessing data within one tenant only.

Comment: so summarising above, i need to validate the tenant action on each action that requires subscription validation ,wouldnt that means more calls to a subscription service and DB ?
In such case do we arite the validation logic in subscription Service which will only return a boolean or do we query the service for all subscription plan attr that user has subscribe to and validate the action in a callee service ?

Comment: Q. i need to validate the tenant action on each action that requires subscription validation
A. Yes
---
Q. wouldnt that means more calls to a subscription service and DB
A. Yes, calls to a service are expected in such cases. Regarding DB, you could implement some caching as subscriptions won't change frequently
---
Q. ....will only return a boolean or do we query...
A. This is up to you considering if maintaining this flag adds some value to you. Value here meaning good reduction in computations